# Not a valid choice in Flask SelectField

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms

After filling form I get that:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNSj2.png)

I was seeing a lot of ways to solve that problem here, in qaru, in reddit and I didn't find solving

So, this is my files:

**webapp.py**

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template, send_file, make_response
from forms import AAForm
from create_plot import ploter
import os

app = Flask(__name__)

SECRET_KEY = os.urandom(32)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = SECRET_KEY

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST']) 
def index():
    form = AAForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        bytes_obj = ploter(form.uniprot_ids.data, form.the_dye.data)
        return send_file(bytes_obj, 
                         attachment_filename='plot.png', 
                         mimetype='image/png')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SelectField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from dyes_list import dyes

class AAForm(FlaskForm):
    uniprot_ids = StringField('Uniprot id', validators=[DataRequired()])
    the_dye = SelectField('Краситель', choices=dyes, validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Паехалиии!')
```

**dyes_list.py**

```py
dyes = [
        (['K', 'R', 'H'], 'Кумасси бриллиантовый синий'),
        (['N', 'Q', 'C'], 'Окрашивание серебром'),
        (['K', 'R', 'H'], 'Амидо черный'),
        (['K', 'R', 'H'], 'Бромфеноловый синий'),
        (['K'], 'Пирогаллоловый красный'),
        (['K', 'R', 'H'], 'Sypro Ruby'),
        (['W'], 'Stain-free'),
        (['H', 'C', 'Q', 'N'], 'Zn-имидазольное негативное окрашивание'),
        ]
```

and **index.html**

```html
<h1>Введите данные</h1>
    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
        <p>
            {{ form.uniprot_ids.label }}<br>
            {{ form.uniprot_ids(size=32) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.uniprot_ids.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>   
        <p>
            {{ form.the_dye.label }}<br>
            {{ form.the_dye(size=1) }}<br>
            {% for error in form.the_dye.errors %}
            <span style="color: red;">[{{ error }}]</span>
            {% endfor %}
        </p>
        <p>{{ form.submit() }}</p>
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </form>
```

**P.s.:** It's strange, but if you invert places keys and values in the "dyes" all will work good (at least you willn't get that problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values are sent back from the [browser as strings](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/stable/fields.html#wtforms.fields.SelectField) which will not validate against an array of strings.

Instead have your values as CSV strings and then split into an array after the form has validated.

```
dyes = [
        ('K,R,H', 'Кумасси бриллиантовый синий'),
        ('N,Q,C', 'Окрашивание серебром'),
        ('K,R,H', 'Амидо черный'),
        ('K,R,H', 'Бромфеноловый синий'),
        ('K', 'Пирогаллоловый красный'),
        ('K,R,H', 'Sypro Ruby'),
        ('W', 'Stain-free'),
        ('H,C,Q,N', 'Zn-имидазольное негативное окрашивание'),
        ]

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = AAForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        _dyes = form.the_dye.data.split(',')
        bytes_obj = ploter(form.uniprot_ids.data, _dyes)
        return send_file(bytes_obj,
                         attachment_filename='plot.png',
                         mimetype='image/png')
    return render_template('index.html', form=form)
```